# How do i get the KO Validation framework to decorate from start?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Please see this simple fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/75qSD/

I want it to decorate the element as invalid from the get go, like it is now you first have to write something in the textbox and then remove it for the validation to show

edti: I know you can do it by code, can you do it by configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/75qSD/1/

I've added the lines:

```
   this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
   this.errors.showAllMessages();
```

Comment: Forgot to mentioned that I known that solution sorry. Will update question

Comment: Haven't found any other way.Since I want this for all my views what I did was to override ko.validation.group(this) and do this.errors.showAllMessages() from that override, works